# how to chop an n dimensional numpy array into an blocks of given size

Tags: python, arrays, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

I want to take the shape of an n-dimensional input array and the shape of the expected block size in python and slice the array into these blocks. But the function only gets the shape of the array and the expected block as arguments and I am required to return the indices of the formed slices only.

```
def foo(input_shape, block_shape):
     **dome something**
     return indices of blocks formed with shape= block_shape
```

For ex:

```
>>> x = foo((2,2,3), (2,2,2))
>>> print(x) 
[( slice(0,2), slice(0,2), slice(0,2) ), 
   (slice(0,2), slice(0,2), slice(1,3) )
]
```

Comment: Can you please post some sample input and sample output?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, I've added an example, hope it makes things clearer